# Django: Project name is duplicated in the template path

Tags: python, django

My project structure is roughly as follows:

```
dinnerproject/
  dinnerproject/
    settings.py
  dinners/
    templates/dinners/
      main.html
  templates/
    base.html
  manage.py
```

In settings.py I've got TEMPLATE configured like so:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

And dinners app is added to INSTALLED_APPS.

I use a TemplateView with template_name = "main.html", which extends base.html.

But when I try to open the page that's supposed to return main.html, I keep getting a *TemplateDoesNotExist* error saying:

```
Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

    django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Users\User\dinnerproject\dinnerproject\templates\main.html (Source does not exist)
    (...)
    django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\User\dinnerproject\dinnerproject\dinners\templates\main.html (Source does not exist)
```

For some reason, my project name is duplicated in the paths, so django cannot find the right directories. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `template_name = "dinners/main.html"`? Duplicating the app name in the templates folder is a convention used to prevent conflicts when multiple apps use the same template names

Answer (score 0):

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'dinnerproject','templates'),
                 os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'dinners','templates'),
                ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**urls.py:**

```
app_name="your app name"
```

This will solve your error